# How do I position an Ajax Slider control NEXT to the textbox instead of below it

Tags: slider

I have them in a table ad when they are rendered, the slider is below the textbox. I want it next to it.

```
  <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="AgeFromLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="AgeFrom">Age From:</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>    
        <asp:TextBox ID="AgeFrom" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" MaxLength="2" Width="30"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AgeFromSlider" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> 
       <asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="AgeFrom" TargetControlID="AgeFromSlider" BoundControlID="AgeFrom" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Orientation="Horizontal" EnableHandleAnimation="true" Length="50">
        </asp:SliderExtender>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="AgeTo">Age To:</asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AgeTo" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" MaxLength="2" Width="30"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AgeToSlider" runat="server"  CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender2" runat="server" BehaviorID="AgeTo" TargetControlID="AgeToSlider" BoundControlID="AgeTo" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Orientation="Horizontal" EnableHandleAnimation="true" Length="50">
</asp:SliderExtender>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using css you can add a `float:left;` property to the text box.

You probably want to create a new css class for this text box or just add it in line so that you don't end up floating every that uses that class unless that is your goal.